# c++ implement the function search array

Tags: c++, loops

I have been given a task as a homework assignment but I am not sure if I have done it correctly. The task is:

Implement a function in c++ that searches for values in a given range. It should fit the following description:

1. INPUT - An unsorted array "A" and two integers "I" and "U"
2. OUTPUT - TRUE if "A" contains an element which is both greater than "I" and      less than "U", FALSE otherwise.

Here is what I've come up with so far. It works and everything but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of going about it?

```
int main()
{
  int array1 [5] = {9, 8, 14, 7, 5};
  int userinput1 = -1;
  int userinput2 = -1;
  int index = -1;
  bool found = false;

  cout << "please enter a number" << endl;
  cin >> userinput1;
  cout << "please enter another number" << endl;
  cin >> userinput2;

  for(index = 0; index < 5; index++)

  {
      if(userinput1 >= array1[index] && userinput2 <= array1[index])
   {
       found = true;
       cout << "Congratulations this number exists" << endl;

       break;
   }
 }

if (!found) cout << "sorry this number doesn't exist" << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: the code is correct. does your assignment specify >=I and <=U .you should put this inside a function

Comment: There's not a hint of a function that fits the specification here. Implement a function that takes three parameters and returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it first and see if it works as expected. Other than that, at first glance instructions say greater or less than, yet you are using `>=` and `<=`.

Also assuming `userinput1` is "I" and `userinput2` is "U", it is being done backwards. Should be `if(userinput1 < array1[index] && userinput2 > array1[index])`.

Comment: Yes the program does work as expected but I just wasn't sure if i was using the right method of execution, e.g. have i done it in a long winded way? is there another way of writing the code? and thank you for re-writing the code I didn't spot that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your assignment require you to display the value when it meets the criteria of being greater than "I" and less than "U"?
Besides that, like it was said earlier, the only thing that needs to be changed is changing your inequality signs to greater than and less than instead of greater than or equal to and less than or equal to.

Comment: this is my assignment word for word:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnd9uqcb62zxoyv/question2.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I think ,better way of doing same thing is using functors. Please refer code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct isInRange
{
    isInRange(int st,int ed) : _st(st),_ed(ed){}
    int _st;
    int _ed;
    bool operator()(int num)
    {
        return (num >=_st && num <=_ed);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> intVec(5);
    intVec.push_back(4);
    intVec.push_back(9);
    intVec.push_back(7);
    intVec.push_back(2);
    intVec.push_back(3);

    std::vector<int>::iterator res = std::find_if(intVec.begin(),intVec.end(),isInRange(10,8));
    if(res == intVec.end())
    {
        std::cout<<"Not Found"<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Found"<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way is not wrong, there are multiple ways of solving the same problem(**welcome to the world of programming!**).
Your approach is one way to solve the question, and it is correct,
i would just say consider using `< >` rather than `>= <=` as per demand of your question.